# How to avoid checkbox box column to export to excel?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, export-to-excel

```
//export header
for (i = 1; i <= this.datagridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    ExcelSheet.Cells[3, i] = this.datagridview1.Columns[i - 1].HeaderText;
}

//export data
for (i = 1; i <= this.datagridview1.RowCount; i++)
{
    for (j = 1; j <= datagridview1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {

        ExcelSheet.Cells[i + 3, j] = datagridview1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[j - 1].Value;
    }
}
```

This is exporting all data from datagridview but I don't want to export "Date " column and "checkbox" column 
[image]

Showing like this
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an additional counter for columns to get the proper output (not just empty columns). Also, you can move the logics of "skipping" columns to a function.

```
int columnsCount = 0;

//export header
for (i = 1; i <= this.datagridview1.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    if (SkipColumn(this.datagridview1.Columns[i - 1]))
        continue;

    columnsCount++;     
    ExcelSheet.Cells[3, columnsCount] = this.datagridview1.Columns[columnsCount - 1].HeaderText;
}

//export data
for (i = 1; i <= this.datagridview1.RowCount; i++)
{
    columnsCount = 0;
    for (j = 1; j <= datagridview1.Columns.Count; j++)
    {
        if (SkipColumn(this.datagridview1.Columns[i - 1]))
            continue;

        columnsCount++;
        ExcelSheet.Cells[i + 3, columnsCount] = datagridview1.Rows[i - 1].Cells[columnsCount - 1].Value;
    }
}

// ...

private bool SkipColumn(DataGridViewColumn column)
{
    return column.GetType() == typeof(DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn)
        || column.Name == "Date";
}
```

You can add any logics to `SkipColumn`. Add any validations, conditions there using `DataGridViewColumn` properties.

Read about `DataGridViewColumn` properties [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcolumn_properties(v=vs.90).aspx).